# User has no Roles after being added to a role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using the Identity framework on asp.net mvc.
After I add a user to the role, I check to see if the person is in the role and there are 0 roles for the user. I checked the database and the ASPnetuserroles has the relationship in there.
Any idea what the issue is?

I am using the AccountController to perform the actions.

Comment: How you check your role?please add your code

Comment: IsInRole() function of the UserManager. Even listing the Roles of the user doesn't show anything. User.Roles

Comment: check your user roles with UserManager.GetRoles();

Comment: I did, there are 0 roles for the user. But I wrote a DataEngine and ran a sql script that select users who are in the AspNetUsersRoles table with the roleid I want, and it works perfect. So I am thinking it is broken on the Microsoft side.